# Why default character_set_server is latin1?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, percona, character-set, utf-8

I am using MySQL 5.5 and when I show variables about charset, I have

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Should I need to change the `character_set_database` and `character_set_server` to `utf8`?

Answer (score 9):

Think about it:

- You are storing data in the database as `latin1`
- You are data is handled internally by mysqld as `latin1`

If data coming from the OS or from the connection is `utf8`, how is mysqld going to treat it?

Rather than guessing or hoping for the best, you could change the incoming character set behavior. With the exception of `information_schema` and `mysql`, take all your databases and set the default character set to `utf8`:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

If you have a specific colllation to go with it, do this:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Here are the collations to choose from:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.collations where CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'utf8';
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+------------+-------------+---------+
| COLLATION_NAME     | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | ID  | IS_DEFAULT | IS_COMPILED | SORTLEN |
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+------------+-------------+---------+
| utf8_general_ci    | utf8               |  33 | Yes        | Yes         |       1 |
| utf8_bin           | utf8               |  83 |            | Yes         |       1 |
| utf8_unicode_ci    | utf8               | 192 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_icelandic_ci  | utf8               | 193 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_latvian_ci    | utf8               | 194 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_romanian_ci   | utf8               | 195 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_slovenian_ci  | utf8               | 196 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_polish_ci     | utf8               | 197 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_estonian_ci   | utf8               | 198 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_spanish_ci    | utf8               | 199 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_swedish_ci    | utf8               | 200 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_turkish_ci    | utf8               | 201 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_czech_ci      | utf8               | 202 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_danish_ci     | utf8               | 203 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_lithuanian_ci | utf8               | 204 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_slovak_ci     | utf8               | 205 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_spanish2_ci   | utf8               | 206 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_roman_ci      | utf8               | 207 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_persian_ci    | utf8               | 208 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_esperanto_ci  | utf8               | 209 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_hungarian_ci  | utf8               | 210 |            | Yes         |       8 |
| utf8_sinhala_ci    | utf8               | 211 |            | Yes         |       8 |
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+------------+-------------+---------+
22 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

You could also run

```
mysql> show collation where charset='utf8';
+--------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| Collation          | Charset | Id  | Default | Compiled | Sortlen |
+--------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| utf8_general_ci    | utf8    |  33 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8_bin           | utf8    |  83 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8_unicode_ci    | utf8    | 192 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_icelandic_ci  | utf8    | 193 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_latvian_ci    | utf8    | 194 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_romanian_ci   | utf8    | 195 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_slovenian_ci  | utf8    | 196 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_polish_ci     | utf8    | 197 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_estonian_ci   | utf8    | 198 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_spanish_ci    | utf8    | 199 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_swedish_ci    | utf8    | 200 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_turkish_ci    | utf8    | 201 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_czech_ci      | utf8    | 202 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_danish_ci     | utf8    | 203 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_lithuanian_ci | utf8    | 204 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_slovak_ci     | utf8    | 205 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_spanish2_ci   | utf8    | 206 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_roman_ci      | utf8    | 207 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_persian_ci    | utf8    | 208 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_esperanto_ci  | utf8    | 209 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_hungarian_ci  | utf8    | 210 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_sinhala_ci    | utf8    | 211 |         | Yes      |       8 |
+--------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

To see the individual charset of a database run this:

```
mysql> show create database sample;
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                                   |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sample   | CREATE DATABASE `sample` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */ |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As for the settings, you could try this:

Add the lines to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
character_set_database=utf8
character_set_server=utf8
```

then restart mysql

I discussed this back on Aug 01, 2011 : [Character Set Encoding in a Table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4227/character-set-encoding-in-a-table/4229#4229)

## CAVEAT (For MySQL DB Servers in Windows)

These commands

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER DATABASE dbname COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

do not work in the Windows Version of MySQL because of the way Windows locks files. The file needed is called `db.opt` which is located in the database subfolder in `datadir`.

You may have to do the following:

- mysqldump that database (no database create info, just table creation and INSERTs)
- drop that database
- create database with the specific charset and collation
- reload in the dump into it

## EPILOGUE

No matter what you do, please perform any changes on a Dev/Staging Server to see if you get the desired effects

## UPDATE 2012-12-05 11:00 EDT

Your Questions

> Should I really change it?

To guarantee the proper treatment of the data, you may want to make sure you have apples-to-apples. Data prepared as one charset and loading it into a table with the database possibly aligning the data as if it sees another charset would probably not display the data with the charset mysqld sees when retrieved and sent back to a DB Connection.  Try loading the database on a Dev/Staging Server and experiment with setting default charsets.

> Why some defaults use `utf8` but some default use `latin1` ?

This would depend on the OS version of the MySQL Binary. Windows versions may have `latin1` while Linux Versions may use `utf8`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed reply. Actually my questions is not about how to change it, but... 1. Should I really change it? 2. Why some defaults use utf8 but some default use latin1

Comment: (thanks again first) This would depend on the OS version of the MySQL Binary. <-- I mean when I am on Ubuntu, why the default is mixed between `latin1` and `utf8`, e.g. `character_set_connection` is utf8 but `character_set_database` is latin1

Comment: @Rolando `[mysqld]
character_set_database=utf8
character_set_server=utf8` don't work.

Comment: I still don't get it...even if the host OS uses some silly limited charset, shouldn't the database by default store text in a charset that can represent any character, even if it accepts input in `latin1` and has to convert it for storage?