# Database convert character_set_server latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql, php, utf-8, magento

I am writing about a problem on the character encoding that i have on my site with Magento. In practice, the special characters do not take utf8 and gives me the classic non-coded characters: Ã.

These are the codes in my database:

```
character_set_client utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database utf8
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results utf8
character_set_server latin1
character_set_system utf8
```

My question is ... the problem of encoding is caused by character_set_server latin1 string? How do I convert my database character_set_server latin1 to utf8? It can be a very simple Query?

Thanks so much

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/why-default-character-set-server-is-latin1

Answer (score 1):

`character_set_server` is not relevant.  The setting on the database is just a default for when you `CREATE TABLE` without specifying a `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET`.

You need

- The bytes in your client to be encoded utf8.
- The connection specifies utf8.  If you are using `mysqli`, use `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')`.
- The *column* in the table must be `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  Look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; if it is not explicit on the column then look at the default for the table.
- If you are doing html output, then it needs `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.